# datasource as readonly - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I have a DataGridView with properties `DataSource = datatable()` and `readonly = false`. `readonly` must be false since there are other columns that can be editable. How do I make all the columns in DataSource read only (not editable)?

The code is as follows:

```
type = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        table= new DataGridView
                         {
                             DataSource = datatable(), // this returns a DataTable object
                             AllowUserToAddRows = false,
                             AllowUserToDeleteRows = false,
                             RowHeadersVisible = false,
                             MultiSelect = false,
                             Name = "AgentTable",
                             AutoSize = true,
                             ReadOnly = false,
                         };
        table.Columns.Add(CreateStartButton());        
        type.Items.Add(" some table");
        type.ReadOnly = false;
        table.Columns.Add(type);
```

EDIT:
 the datagridview will contain 4 columns.

- First column, each cell is a button (readonly doesnt matter)
- second column, each cell is a drop down box (readonly is false)
- third and fourth columns are created as DataTable object so (readonly must be true)

so my question is how to make the third and forth column read-only?

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy to iterate the columns after you create them all. I'd use something like this, but I'm calling it pseudocode because I don't know if DataColumn is the correct data type:

```
foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns) {
    col.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: Okay, then maybe just alter table.Columns[2] and table.Columns[3] that way if you're never going to change the structure. Otherwise, add a conditional inside my foreach loop to test the column name against a list of column names you want to keep read-only / editable.

Comment: <code> col.Table.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true; <code> is giving exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object. and when form loads then the column is NOT readonly.... Some cells in the column are blank and remaining are filled. can that be a problem?